Talagrand/Bousquet's inequality for U-processes
I have a U-process of the form
$$\left\lbrace Z_n(g) := \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} (g(S_i) - E[g(S_i)] )(g(S_j') - E[g(S_j')]) : g \in \mathcal{G} \right\rbrace,$$
where $S_1,\ldots,S_n,S_1',\ldots,S_n'$ are i.i.d.
Would there be an exponential bound relating
$\sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}} Z_n(g)$ to $E \sup_{g \in \mathcal{G}} Z_n(g)$, in the spirit of Bousquet's inequality or Talagrand's inequality for the supremum of empirical processes?
